# Bug with ActiveRecords

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I can't delete information about tables and columns from ActiveRecord's cache.
I'm using ActiveRecord for Ruby without Rails.

```
require 'active_record'
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => "mysql2",
    :database  => #
    :password => #
)   
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :peoples
end
enter code here
class Persons < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :peoples
end

class People < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :persons
end


Person.new

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'vkusno.people' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `people`'

Persons.new
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'vkusno.persons' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `persons`'
```

But I try to connect to a Database without some table and columns.

Before I had a table in the database, "People, Peoples, Person, Persons",  but I drop all my tables and restarted my server a few times.

If I change my database to sqlite, I get some don't exist tables, which it I'm working and drop that tables too.

How I can repair it?

**UPD**

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

class AddFirst < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :persons do |t|
      t.integer :idd
      t.string :name
      t.string :href
      t.string :sex
      t.string :country
      t.string :city
      t.boolean :can_message
      t.boolean :can_wall
      t.string :photo
      t.boolean :is_friend
      t.boolean :is_client
    end
    create_table :people do |x|
      x.integer :id_general
      x.string :description
    end
  end
  def down
    drop_table :persons
    drop_table :people
  end
  def keys
    add_column :persons, :peoples_id, :integer
    add_index :persons, :peoples_id
  end
end

> AddFirst.new.up
-- create_table(:persons)
CREATE TABLE `persons` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `idd` int(11), `name` varchar(255), `href` varchar(255), `sex` varchar(255), `country` varchar(255), `city` varchar(255), `can_message` tinyint(1), `can_wall` tinyint(1), `photo` varchar(255), `is_friend` tinyint(1), `is_client` tinyint(1)) ENGINE=InnoDB

-- create_table(:people)
CREATE TABLE `people` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `id_general` int(11), `description` varchar(255)) ENGINE=InnoDB
=> {}

AddFirst.new.keys
-- add_column(:persons, :peoples_id, :integer)
ALTER TABLE `persons` ADD `peoples_id` int(11)
-- add_index(:persons, :peoples_id)
CREATE INDEX `index_persons_on_peoples_id` ON `persons` (`peoples_id`) 
=> nil



> Person.new
=> #<Person id: nil, id_general: nil, description: nil>
> Persons.new
=> #<Persons id: nil, idd: nil, name: nil, href: nil, sex: nil, country: nil, city: nil, can_message: nil, can_wall: nil, photo: nil, is_friend: nil, is_client: nil>
> People.new
=> #<People id: nil, id_general: nil, description: nil>
```

Comment: are you seeing the SQL being generated by AR when you run this code? If not, add `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` after your require.  It may give some clues as to what is happening

Answer (score 0):

**Understanding how class names are mapped to table names**

You need to understand how `ActiveRecord` decides the table name for a model.

If you have a class `Person`, the default table name will be `people`. AR does this by calling the `tableize` method on the class name, like this:

```
'Person'.tableize  # => "people"
```

or

```
Person.name.tableize   # => "people"
```

That means, for the `Person` class, you should create the `people` table (unless you want to override the default). Make sure you get the spelling correct; `peoples` will *not* work.

That also means you should *not* have another class `People` because the default table name will also be `people`:

```
'People'.tableize  #=> "people"
```

There will be a clash, or at best, you'll confuse yourself.

It's not a good idea to use `persons` as the table name, unless you're overriding the default. That's because AR will not generate `persons` as the table name for class `Person`.

*I strongly encourage you to read and understand the [ActiveRecord basics guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) before you try anything else.*

**Modeling the real world**

I'm also not sure why you want `Person` to belong to `:peoples`.

Can you describe the real-world scenario you're trying to represent?

Examples:

- a person has many books
- a person belongs to an organization.