# Reinitialize a ruby Class

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

How i can solve it ?

```
class Person
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Person.
```

I want to reinitialize a class.

Comment: I think you should explain your problem a little more. Are you defining the class both times?

Comment: Yes. I want to change the class, that i'm declare before.
Maybe exist some solution with free memory.
I think it can solve my problem with ActiveRecord
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506860/bug-with-activerecords

Comment: Allpodo, I hate to say this, but my answer (while correct) is a dirty hack and is extremely unlikely to solve your problem. You should use clearer class names and table names. ActiveRecord defines a convention that relates your class name to your table name, which you can override if you wish. You might need to restart every Rails server process after dropping those tables, and do `reload!` in the rails console.

Comment: Why don’t you just remove the first definition or make it descend from the same superclass? You get an error for a reason.

Comment: Please explain how you're using the first definition, and why. I'm 99.99% sure you can accomplish your goal another way. Trying to change the superclass very likely introduce subtle bugs.

Comment: I had problem with ActiveRecord, and i think, my one Class exist in the cache and i can't delete this.
If i'm create instance of class "Person", it is to be instance of class "People" and i can't change it.
I'm wan't to use ActiveRecord without Rails.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you need the first class definition. Can you just replace it with a `require` of the second definition? It might help if you posted more code. What are you trying to accomplish with the 2 definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (sort of) do this.

```
# initial definition
class Person
end

# new definition
class OverridePerson < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Person = OverridePerson
```

- Please see comment by @Andrew Marshall. You can undefine Person, then define it without creating dummy class `OverridePerson`

Similarities to what you want to do:

- `Person` will refer to the new class

Differences to what you want to do:

- Existing instances will not change their class
- Class methods and variables will be clobbered
- Person.name will be OverridePerson, but you can override that to be "Person"

Your use cases might be:

- redefine `Person`, duck-typing it to fool a library or an application. IMO this is perfectly legit for testing purposes, though ActiveRecord::Base will be a hard one to duck-type. I recommend using FakeAR or RSpec mocks, or stubs on the original class
- You want to make a class called `Person`, but it is already defined. In this case I recommend namespacing within a module.

Comment: Yeah... Ah well, whoever it is can only do that once! Feel free to expand on my answer.

Comment: I also recommend looking into ruby 2.0 refinements, where you can monkey patch a class, but select where you make the monkey-patchings available.

Comment: Could be done without creating a dummy constant by either directly reassigning: `Person = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do ... end`, or by completely removing the constant first: `Object.send(:remove_const, :Person)`.

Comment: Sorry, had to downvote. Reassigning a class name (a constant) is almost always a bad idea. I get the impression that the OP doesn't really understand the implications. Those who are more informed shouldn't rush to give an answer on such a questionable, uh, question. Sure it's nice to get rep on our answers, but I don't want to lose sight of actually *teaching* good principles via careful answers. Hopeful OP will come back and clarify.

Comment: I've been there, and when I asked questions like this, I used to hate being treated with kid gloves and being given the "Why would you want to?" or "Don't" answers, which are totally uninformative. The OP is trying to something fairly advanced by using ActiveRecord without Rails, so he deserves no less than a straight answer with recommendations on what to do instead..

Comment: Note that I said *almost* always a bad idea. But you wouldn't know without asking. It *would* be a bad idea if OP didn't understand (which I suspect is the case). Sometimes it's a fine line between "advanced" and "bad"; and we don't want to help people shoot themselves in the foot. So finding the purpose would be especially important here.

Answer (score 6):

Once you've created a class in ruby, you can't alter its superclass by reopening it.
That's why you're getting the `TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Person.` error.

Other answers have provided alternatives, but it is important to note that none of them modify the existing `Person` class, but actually create a new class and reassigns the old Person constant to the new class, under the limitations already stated by @user1158559 in his answer.

Comment: +1, even though it's not really an answer. But I think it's good as the "voice of reason". Changing the superclass is a bad idea.

Comment: I like to think that it is an answerr in the sense that it clarifies that what the OP wants to do is effectively impossible. Other answers, including the accepted one, do provide alternatives that do not solve the exact problem, but that may be useful in different scenarios, even though why anyone would want to do this is beyond my understanding.Either way, thank you for considering this answer worthy of an upvote @Kelvin =)

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you use the same class signature every time.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def x
  end
end


class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def y
  end
end
```

Comment: Even better, if you have autoloading, and `Person` is a model, just reference `Person` to make sure the original definition is autoloaded from `app/models/person.rb`. Then, reopen the class definition without another reference to the superclass.

Comment: Also, specifying the superclass every time isn't very DRY, and unnecessary if you can guarantee the load order.

Comment: @user1158559 if `Person` is a rails model, it will be loaded when you use it. Otherwise, just `require` it from the code that needs it.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the answer you look for, but its a way to `undefine a class` or a constant so you can redefine it, but it will lose all the original methods:

```
Object.send(:remove_const, :Person)
```